# Add to my Page's Favourites tab

Tags: facebook-pages

I do not seem to have the Add to my Page's favourites tab on my business page when I look at it which means apart from the Like button I do not have my business showing with my profile picture on other FB user's sites.  How do I load this?

Comment: Are you trying to add your own page to the same pages "favorites"?